# What is the best semantic HTML element for Math formulas and numbers (inline)?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I write a lot of mathematical articles and wonder what the best way is to mark numbers/formulas within text.

I was using Latex mostly, but I would try to avoid it and use an inline HTML element instead, where suitable.

For now I am using `<code>123</code>` (styled as inline with CSS), which results in easy to read text blocks such as:

[image: example inline code]

But since it is not `code`, it is semantically not correct.

#### Element Research

I tried to find the semantically most suitable HTML element. These are my results:

1. The `<var>` HTML element:

> The  element represents a variable in the context of either mathematics or computer programming.

But not for number(s), formula(s).

2. Also `<q>` (inline quote), `<abbr>` or `<dfn>` do not seem applicable.
3. `<data>` seems a bit broad and goes with a data attribute.
4. `<mark>` would be a candidate.

> "This tag highlights content because of its special relevance in some context."

As you can see, I am guessing around and need advice.

### The <math> Tag

There is a separate `<math>` element ([reference](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/maths.html)).

> The  element is used to include math expressions in the current line.

It is designed for the usage with [MathML](https://www.w3.org/Math/). HTML cannot be used inside, as the content gets rendered with expected MathML syntax.

Example:

```
<math>&int;_a_^b^{f(x)<over>1+x} dx</math>
<math>Z<sub>1</sub> = 100 €</math>
```

Result:

∫_a_^b^{f(x)1+x} dx
Z<sub>1</sub> = 100 €

The first example works fine, the second one fails (and is not even rendered).

> ... complete MathML expression must be contained in  tags. (...) The presence of enclosing  tags should be a reasonable heuristic test for MathML content. (...) However, the problem of supporting HTML in MathML presents many difficulties. (...) Therefore, at present, the MathML specification does not permit any HTML elements within a MathML expression.

Comment: Thinking more about this issue, I start to believe that the recent `<math>` tag should have been named `<mathml>` since it is only for usage with MathML. And the `<math>` tag should actually be used for declaring **any mathematical context**.

Comment: It looks like `<math>` has very little browser support: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/MathML/Element/math

Comment: I have started to use `<mark>` for all mathematical elements in my articles.